# How to enable required authentification in server side blazor app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am writing a server sided blazor app for our intranet.

Is there anyway to force the user to login before he/she can access any other side besides of login and register?

In ASP.NET Webforms it was possible with the Web.config file.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" defaultUrl="default.aspx" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply annotate your Index component with the Authorize attribute as follows:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@attribute [Authorize]
```

That will initiate the authentication flow before the user can access other resources....

Hope this helps...

Comment: Yes but I need to do this manually for every page, otherwise people can just type the real URL.

Comment: You can add the Authorize attribute to the _Imports.razor file, and exclude specific components, such as login by applying the Anonymous attribute within the component...